# How to customize style of Github profile repo?

Tags: github

Assume your Github username is `xxxx`, Github supports a special profile repo `https://github.com/xxxx/xxxx` to render its `README.md` on your profile page `https://github.com/xxxx` above pinned repos.

However, it seems to only support markdown, which means I could not customize style (e.g. color, size, layout) through vanilla html, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60331472/github-markdown-cannot-change-any-style-by-inline-css-and-class).

Are there any workaround solutions to customize style of Github profile repo to make it look more fancy?

Answer (score 0):

please click the link and read the documentation.
[Github Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/managing-your-profile-readme)

Create a repository and type a repository name that matches your GitHub username.

select public and Click **Create repository**.

Create a **readme.md** file and type in your profile details

My github profile : [Github Profile](https://github.com/anagh534)

Readme.md file example: [Example](https://github.com/anagh534/anagh534)

Answer (score -1):

You can make your profile fancy by using many icons/logos/gif

you will not need any colors then, check out this resource which has the links to how you can generate a very colorful and relevant profile using some generators

a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_xvLSmnXYuI) which can help you of using the online resources which can make it easy for you

[bit.ly/Improveyourgithubprofile](https://udzial.com/make-your-github-profile-awesome/) <-- all the resources here

This is my profile and just with the markdown [image]